# $.fullCalendar.formatDate is not a function when using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have problem with not recognizing .formatDate function in fullCalendar.

This is my code:

```
<div id='calendar' style="width:100%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.ready = function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#eventTitle').val("");
                $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(date), "'dd/MM/yyyy'"));
                $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(date), "HH:mm"));
                ShowEventPopup(date);
            }
        })
    };

    function ShowEventPopup(date) {
        ClearPopupFormValues();
        $('#popupEventForm').show();
        $('#eventTitle').focus();
    }

    function ClearPopupFormValues() {
        $('#eventID').val("");
        $('#eventTitle').val("");
        $('#eventDateTime').val("");
        $('#eventDuration').val("");
    }
</script>
```

I have read all similar questions I've found, but I still don't see what's the problem. 
What I am trying to accomplish is to get modal on field (for day) click, but instead I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $.fullCalendar.formatDate is not a function`

I've saw in one of the questions that usually problem is caused by missing reference to moment.js, but I have all referenced in my Layout view page:

```
 <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/moment-range/lib/moment-range.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" />
</environment>
```

Can someone spot the potential problem? What I am doing wrongly? 
fullCalendar template is shown on page, but .formatDate is not recognized as function.

This is error in browser:

[image]

Comment: I don't know about fullcalendar.js but i check on internet and look at this link here: `https://fullcalendar.io/docs/` and I didn't see any formatDate function in it. I believe you can check the documentaion about fullcalender and find what u wish :) hope this help

Comment: which version of fullcalendar you are using ? formatDate is deprecated from v2 and accepted a very different format prior to 1.3 [https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/utilities/formatDate/]

Comment: @MitBhatt I have just realized that I have installed v2 and looking examples from lower version so I guess I will need to use momentJs to format dates, since formatDate() doesn't exists in fullCalender v2

Comment: @nemo_87 Yes, if you upgrading from lower version, refer [https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/] for further details

Comment: @MitBhatt Thanks! New version now uses: $.fullCalendar.moment() instead formatDate();